# Is there a story I should be paying attention to in Dark Souls?

Tags: dark-souls

What's the story in Dark Souls? Also is there anything to be gained from watching the cutscenes other than cool cinematics?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The cinematics are fairly plain, and don't reveal much of the storyline. You get carried off by a crow... you ring a bell... you ring another bell. It's all very exciting. (Sarcasm)

The real story can be found in the items you find, and by talking to the NPCs you come across. Talking to them after each major event (killing a boss, ringing a bell etc.) reveals more about the story, and the lore of the game than the cut scenes ever will. This is (in my opinion) what makes the game so enjoyable - not only are you fighting for your survival, but you are also searching for the clues that reveal what you need to do next.

Failing that, if you can't be bothered investigating it all, some youtubers like [VaatiVidya](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLWLedd0Zw3c5RCXboUsPwHsZJlXB2CzCz) have done a lot of good research into the story and it's characters.

Comment: Hmm, sarcasm. +1.